# MongoDB List of Subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about Subdocuments. Lets say I have a user Database like this:

```
db.users.insertMany([
{
    username: "test",
    projectA: [
        {
            tags: ['1234', '23454']
        }

    ]
},

{
    username: "test2",
    projectA: [
        {
            tags: ['1dfdfsdf', '234dfdfdf54']
        }

    ]
},
]);
```

Below the User Document I have Subdocuments with the Projects. Let's say, that one of the Project is called "ProjectA". And under this document I store the data of the Project, in my example some tags.

I have no use for the whole User-Model, because it can be a lot of data. What I want is a list with all tags in the Database under the User and projectA.

I use NodeJS with mongoose to get the data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$match` for filtering and `$project` for getting the subset of the data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { username: "test" } },
    { $project: {"projectA.tags": 1} }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BuPVUpFdB_A)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB and Mongoose have no built-in functionality to exactly what you want.
After querying the database, you will have to write custom code to loop through the array of documents being returned.

Something like this:

```js
db.collection.find({})
.lean()
.sort({data:1})
.limit(10)
.then(data=>{

//Process your data here using custom codes

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index].ProjectA.tags;
    console.log(element);
    }
})

.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Here I assume that the project filed is always going to be called `ProjectA` for and the tag filed will always be called `tags`.

Comment: This sounds like a real performance problem, especially when I want to get for example the last 10 added Tags, I have to go through the whole Database every time. In MySQL it would be a simple Query with sort and limit. Or maybe the whole Database Design should be different? Lets say, that there are different Projects and Users. And a user can participate in different Projects. And I have a page, where I have some statistics about the Project. Like for example the list with tags. What's the best way to design the Database. Every way I think of goes in direction of Table based relational DB.

Comment: You can do limit and sort in MongoDB as well. Other operators like `$or` and `$and` are also available. I suggest you check out the MongoDB doc.